# Visual Stidio Code не показывает где заканчивается блок

Tags: visual-studio-code

Есть код на php в котором есть шаблон блока на html. Если стоит язык html, то видно где начинается и заканчивается div (Идет выделение участка кода). Но если поставить язык php, то в идет начало и конец всех div в файле. Как настроить, чтобы при php он также показывал начало и конец блока div?

В Atom такой проблемы не было.

Comment: Доброе утро! Установите расширение для PHP, если ещё не установлено